# Fine Uploader get the allowed extensions to use on other parts

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

I am trying to implement the `jquery fine uploader` and now i need to get the allowed extension from the uploader and use it in determining if the file is allowed or not to upload on custom function.

There is a method to get the allowed extension but is a private api.

```
 _getValidationBase: function(buttonId) {
                var extraButtonSpec = this._extraButtonSpecs[buttonId];
                return extraButtonSpec ? extraButtonSpec.validation : this._options.validation;
            },
```

I cannot find any public api to get the validation/ allowed extensions in fine uploader.

**Is there any method to get the allowed extension to use publicly?**

**Note:**

I am using Fine Uploader 5.15.5

If the question is unclear could further add more informations.

Comment: Is this tagged right? Not sure how `jquery-ui` peeps can help here.

Comment: @Twisty Since i was using the `jquery-fine-uploader` and there is no any tags for this. So, had tagged in there. Removed for relevance.

Comment: Cool. Can just tag jQuery